# Crystal grouping sum problem

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm trying to do a sum on a group with a total of the sum at the end of the report.

Basically in the group header field I need to sum 5 fields to create a total. This is easy with a simple formula that just adds up the fields which I place in the header.
I now need to have a grand total at the end of the report.
The details section is taken by notes assigned to the goods in the header

My data should be along these lines:

```
+Group Header
Apple 2
Orange 3
Pear 0
Total: 5
+Details
Note 1
Note 2

+Group Header
Apple 1
Orange 4
Pear 2
Total: 7
+Details
Note 1
Note 2
Note 3

+Group Header
Apple 1
Orange 0
Pear 1
Total: 2
+Details
Note 1

+Report Footer
Grand Total: 14
```

The problem I encounter is that when I try to get a grand total, it sums by the details section so my grand total would be '33' as it has taken the total for each group and totaled it by the amount of notes that are there (ie: total 5 * 2 notes in the first group).

I've tried using summary by group etc and I just can't quite get it there, any help greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try a running total field - you can use formulas to decide when a number is included in the total or not.

Comment: Trying to find the correct analogy to explain my stupidity but I'm coming up dry.
Yes a running total field that evaluates on change of group works a treat... thx

Comment: I'll get my wife to help with the analogy - she is good with that sort of thing...